# how to select columns by column index in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to select columns in a table in SQL Server by there index.

Something like

```
SELECT column1 TO column5 
FROM Table1
```

Is there any method like above or any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: NO! You have to specify the column names.

Comment: so i have specify each column name in statement for selection?

Comment: Note that in a relational database columns don't really have an index. `create table (a int, b int)` is conceptually the same as `create table (b int, a int)`